# Show computer name on Windows desktop computer icon

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-registry

I know how to do this in Windows XP, as explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/298296/113526), but it seems that `LocalizedString` in `HKLM\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` is locked in Windows 7. Every time I try to edit it, I get the following error, *Cannot edit LocalizedString: Error writing the value's new contents*

Does anyone know how I can edit this to show the computer name on the desktop’s "Computer" icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Synetech, thanks a lot for pointing me to the not so obvious, I probably would have never seen it had not been for your help (upvoted your answer), and yes I was already running as admin, I have UAC set to elevate without prompt for admins (also tried running "as administrator", running from cmd prompt started as admin, etc, etc, but nothing worked) but didn't work

**Fix:**  Turns out, that key is stupidly configured (imho), neither System, nor Administrators had write access to that key, I had to take ownership of the key then give administrators write access to be able to modify it.

Comment: Finally you find it! Good news  :)

Comment: `Turns out, that key is stupidly configured (imho), neither System, nor Administrators had write access to that key, I had to take ownership of the key then give administrators write access to be able to modify it.`   Um, yes, that’s what I said.

Comment: @Synetech actually, that's what you said after I figured it out the hard way, thanks to hints from both you and climenole (and upvoted both answers), but whatever

Comment: Okay; I don’t know what happens behind the scenes, I can only see the timestamps. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

That key is [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc982153.aspx). To write to it, you need to [give yourself write permission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728310%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to it.

Comment: Hmm, curious that somebody decided to rescind an up-vote today after almost a year without explanation. I can’t address any problems or provide help if no comment is left. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Open regedit with the Sysinternals command line utility PsExec with **-i -d -s** switches:

*Example:*  "`C:\Program Files\Sysinternals Suite\PsExec.exe" -i -d -s C:\Windows\regedit.exe`

(This works even with the «Legacy» registry entries for example...)

PsExec: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Hope this help. Let us know.

Comment: I tried simmilar approach `psexec -i -s cmd` then ran regedit from there, but didn't work, as I stated in my own answer, I found out that neither **administrators** nor **system** had write access to this key

Comment: May be the wrong switches...

Comment: wrong switches?

Comment: l instead of i ... (I do it the 1st time I used PsExec... :-S  )

Comment: got you, I guess I'm old school, having the console there before I launch that and other commands and perhaps see if I get some error make me feel warm and fuzzy   :)